# How to sort HashMap when HashMap does not maintain insertion order?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, getvalue, entryset

In an interview I was asked to sort HashMap by values. Even after I write such a program, it does not print the HashMap in sorted order. Can someone please explain?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<Integer,String> x= new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    x.put(3, "arsfd");
    x.put(5, "3453");
    x.put(6, "sdfsaf");
    x.put(8, "wetr");
    x.put(11, "cbncvnbv");
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    mylist.addAll(x.values());
    Collections.sort(mylist);       
    HashMap<Integer,String> y= new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    for(int p=0;p<x.size();p++) {
        System.out.println(mylist.get(p));
        y.put((Integer) getKey(x,mylist.get(p)), mylist.get(p));
    }
    System.out.println(y.toString());
}
public static Integer getKey(HashMap<Integer,String> x,Object v) {
    for(Entry<Integer, String> oo:x.entrySet()) {
        if(oo.getValue()==v)
            return (Integer)oo.getKey();
    }
    return null;}
```

Comment: The question makes no sense. You could use another Map implementation that preserves insertion order, or create a list of entries and sort that list. But not sort a HashMap.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SortedMaps orders their entries by their key, not their value.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course I knew that, I was just making sure you were paying attention `:-)`

Comment: reopen my question

Comment: Read [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values) for options. TL;DR: `HashMap` itself cannot be sorted, but you can sort its entries and then store them in a `LinkedHashMap` which conserves insertion order.